Подчет количества значений в наборе данных
Есть набор
Товар1, Поставщик, ..., 
Товар1, Поставщик, ..., 
Товар2, Поставщик, ..., 
Товар2, Поставщик, ..., 
Товар3, Поставщик, ..., 

Надо получить точно такой же набор данных, но добавить количество товаров в наборе. То есть,
Товар1, Поставщик, ..., 2
Товар1, Поставщик, ..., 2
Товар2, Поставщик, ..., 2
Товар2, Поставщик, ..., 2
Товар3, Поставщик, ..., 1

Как это можно сделать? Понимаю, что через группировку, но если просто добавить count(goodname) то нет, так не работает.  MSSQL
Спасибо

Посмотрите на оконные функции
Оконные функции SQL простым языком с примерами
добавьте в Ваш Select колонку
count(*) over (partition by goodname) as count_goodname

